# How to include trim condition in mean function

Tags: r, function, mean

I am trying to create my own mean function.
I have the following line of code already. However, I want to add trim to the argument such that lower and upper bounds outliers are excluded. Please how do I do this?

Below is the mean function I currently have:

```r
mymeanfunction <- function(x) {
  xbar <- sum(x)/length(x)
  xbar 
}
```

Comment: Rewrite the function declaration as `mymeanfunction = function(x, trim)` then before computing the mean, trim the input vector `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? The function below accepts extra arguments `na.rm` and the dots argument so that the call can ask for other whiskers' lengths via [`boxplot.stats`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html) argument `coef`.

```
mymean <- function(x, trim, na.rm = FALSE, ...) {
  out <- boxplot.stats(x, ...)$out
  y <- x[!x %in% out]
  mean(y, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `trim=` argument of `mean` considers the percentage of `quantile`s to remove from head and tail of a vector before computing the mean. So you can write:

```
mymeanfunction <- function(x, trim=0) {
  if (trim > 0) {
    q <- quantile(x, c(0 + trim, 1 - trim))
    x <- x[x > q[1] & x < q[2]]
  }
  xbar <- sum(x)/length(x)
  xbar
}
```

To implement `NA` handling you could enhance the function like this:

```
mymeanfunction <- function(x, trim=0, na.rm=FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  }
  if (anyNA(x)) {
    xbar <- NA_real_
  } else {
    if (trim > 0) {
      q <- quantile(x, c(0 + trim, 1 - trim))
      x <- x[x > q[1] & x < q[2]]
    }
    xbar <- sum(x)/length(x)
  }
    xbar
}

mymeanfunction(x, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0.6362622
mymeanfunction(x, trim=.1, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0.66136

## compare
mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0.6362622
mean(x, trim=.1, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0.66136
```

If there's no `NA` in the data, we don't need to specify `na.rm=TRUE`.

Note, that `mean` will be much faster, since computation is implemented in `C` language. But for educational purposes you see what's going on now.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
x <- c(runif(10), NA_real_)
```